# How to call VF page from Lightning component picklist?

Tags: visualforce, lightning, picklist

Here is my scenario, I have created a lightning component with pick-list values.
I have pick-list values as Preview of Record,download Record.
When i select Download Record, i want to down the record as pdf automatically.
I searched google for help, i see some posts where they have create quick action button and calling vf page.below is the reference of that method.
https://medium.com/@ToAnshulVerma/lightning-generate-pdf-within-lightning-experience-with-salesforce-data-cd82ae626cc3
But in my case i want to do the same functionality with Pick-list.
I want know that how we can vf page when pick-list value is selected.

Thanks,
Lakshminarayana

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to download pdf from a Lightning component when "Download Record" is selected in the dropdown.
We can use a Visualforce page which is rendered as pdf for this. Then you can download this pdf by creating an anchor tag and clicking on it through JavaScript (https://stackoverflow.com/a/34694012/6415948).

```
let link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = "<URL GOES HERE>";
link.download = 'file.pdf';
link.target = "_blank"; // So that pdf is opened in other tab.
link.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
```